# checking extra spaced between names in data frames

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to find the extra space between names in data frame but getting the error below .
please help me what i am doing wrong.

i want to add the new column to the database and give the the left cell have extra spaces .

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(name=c("Tijor Maikin","McKaren Blanken","Matrick Powell","Larry Bishop","Johnson Patterson","Richard pack","Nancy john Alli","McLaura kukeza ","Shellby  sen", "John N. Murphy", "Alex Hr Nelson"))
df1 <- df %>% mutate(across(`new name` = ifelse(countSpaces(df[["name"]])>1,"have spaces","")))

Error in `.fun()`:
i In argument: `across(...)`.
Caused by error in `across()`:
! `...` must be empty.
x Problematic argument:
* new name = ifelse(countSpaces(df[["name"]]) > 1, "have spaces", "")
```

required output is
[image]

Comment: Hi samrr_tr! A couple of things: 1. you haven't defined countSpaces in the code you included. 2. the base R syntax and the dplyr syntax don't play well together, I wouldn't use them together if I were you. 3. across is used across multiple columns, and has a fairly specific syntax, which it doesn't appear you have used

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're wanting something like this:

```
# turn consecutive white spaces into a single whitespace
df1 <- df %>% mutate(`new name` = str_replace_all(name, "  ", " "))
```

Or perhaps something like this:

```
# find rows with more than one whitespace in a row in them
df1 <- df %>% mutate(`new name` = grepl("  ", name))
```

Comment: i have updated the required output

Answer (score 0):

An approach using `grepl`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(spaces = if_else(grepl(" .* ", name), "more than one space", ""))
                name              spaces
1       Tijor Maikin                    
2    McKaren Blanken                    
3     Matrick Powell                    
4       Larry Bishop                    
5  Johnson Patterson                    
6       Richard pack                    
7    Nancy john Alli more than one space
8    McLaura kukeza  more than one space
9       Shellby  sen more than one space
10    John N. Murphy more than one space
11    Alex Hr Nelson more than one space
```